# loop to Executor Service

Tags: java, executorservice

I want to use JavaExecutor Service for the below:

```
for(String s : multiMap.keySet()){
    for(String s1 : listB){
      for(String s2 : listC){
      //API call
      }
    }
 }
```

as in for loops the time taken for completing is too much and is taking for ever. So i am thinking of using this in an executorService so that the tasks can be completed sooner. Can any one please suggest how to do this using Executor service ?

Note : Using Java 7.

Answer (score 4):

The following snippet is an example of using ExecutorService for this question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int numRunnables = 3;

    ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listC = new ArrayList<String>();

    BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(numRunnables, true);
    RejectedExecutionHandler handler = new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy();
    ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(numRunnables, numRunnables, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue, handler);

    HashMap<String, String> multiMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(String s : multiMap.keySet()){

        executor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(String s1 : listB){
                    for(String s2 : listC){
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }       

    executor.shutdown();
    while (executor.isTerminated() == false){
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
}
```

In addition, I think 'ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);' is a rarely used function, but it's easier to access and so often used by initial users of ExecutorService. When there are lots of Runnables each of which taking relatively long, using the executor from Executors.newFixedThreadPool cause memory problems and then take much longer compared to the ThreadPoolExecutor created like my snippet above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. So do you suggest using ThreadPoolExecutor as the loop goes m*n*p times? @Tom

Comment: Can you please suggest how to use ThreadPoolExecutor for this task please? what if the other two are multimap instead of a list? can ThreadPoolExecutor still be applied?

Comment: Once the innermost code (inside String s2 : listC) in the Runnables does not modify the same collection, an ExecutorService can be applied. If does, use 'synchronized (theCollection) { .... }' to wrap the code that modifies 'theCollection'.

Comment: @MSR, The ConcurrentHashMap class from the java.util.concurrent package is a thread-safe implementation of Map that offers far better concurrency than synchronizedMap (and far superior scalability over Hashtable).

Comment: @Tom how do I use a similar implementation if I need to return a value each time on the loop? I need to use Callable instead of Runnable, but BlockingQueue only works with Runnable.. Any suggestions?

Comment: @GuyTal You can try a different ExecutorService instead of my example above.

Comment: @Tom does it matter if the executor runnable declaration is inside or outside of the loop?

Comment: @GuyTal now I think creating the runnable outside the loop is better than repeatedly creating the same runnable in the loop. You can move runnable declaration outside the loop.